# Missing Vala Package Valaconfig.cmake

Tags: cmake, configuration, vala

I'm starting to learn vala, after a couple of years working with java.

I have a sample application, that uses cmake to compile.

Compilation throws an error after I run the command

```
 cmake  ..

 Could not find a package configuration file provided by Vala with any of the following names: ValaConfig.cmake   vala -config.cmake
```

How do I solve this? I couldn't find anything on the net.

My system is Ubuntu 19.04 .

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

CMake is a build system that makes use of modules. So it's probably not finding the relevant [Vala modules](https://github.com/jakobwesthoff/Vala_CMake).

From [this answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16271/using-cmake-on-juno) on Elementary OS Stack Exchange is looks like it is common practise for elementary OS projects to assume the modules are installed globally. That answer recommends `apt install cmake-elementary`.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, but sudo apt install cmake-elementary returns Unable to locate package cmake-elementary

Comment: I mis-read your question. I thought you were trying to compile an existing project and assumed it was from elementary OS. If you have started your own and are following a tutorial or another project's structure that uses CMake then try installing cmake-vala. Otherwise a lot of people, including myself, use the Meson build system